# Parsing JSON in VB.NET

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, parsing

I am trying to parse the following data returned in JSON

```
{
    "Id":8151302,
    "Status":"Accepted",
    "Response":"0",
    "Price":"0.88",
    "Detail":"https://api.test.com/Redirect/Index 3eae1b02"
}
```

This is what I have tried using:

```
sresult = sresult.Replace("""""", String.Empty)

If sresult.Contains("Status"":""Accepted") Then
    Dim parts = sresult.Replace("{", String.Empty).Replace("}", String.Empty).Split(",")

    For i As Int16 = 0 To parts.Length - 1
        If parts(i).StartsWith("Detail"":") Then
            app.Outcome.RedirectURL = parts(i).Substring(12)
        End If

        If parts(i).StartsWith("Price"":") Then
            lendertier.LenderComm = CDec(parts(i).Substring(11))
        End If

        If parts(i).StartsWith("Id") Then
            app.Outcome.LenderReference = parts(i).Substring(15)
        End If
    Next

    AcceptLead()
    Return True
```

The returned results I get after parsing are

> URL:
>
> REF:
>
> PRICE:£0.00

And it should be:

> URL: https://api.test.com/Redirect/Index 3eae1b02
>
> ID: 8151302
>
> PRICE: 0.88

I tried deserializing it as well. I get the same results:

```
Dim sReason As String = "Unknown"
    Dim JSON As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim SH As SandhurstData = JSON.Deserialize(Of SandhurstData)(sResult)
    If SH.Status = "Accepted" Then
        app.Outcome.RedirectURL = SH.RedirectURL
        app.Outcome.LenderReference = SH.ApplicationRef
        lendertier.LenderComm = SH.Commission
        AcceptLead()
        Return True
    End If
    sReason = SH.Reason
    If Not SH.ValidationErrors Is Nothing Then
        If (SH.ValidationErrors.Count > 0) Then
            For Each e As String In SH.ValidationErrors
                sReason &= e + "; "
            Next
        End If
    End If
    DeclineLead(sReason.Trim())
    Return False    
End Function

<Serializable> _
Public Class SandhurstData
    Public Property Status() As String
    Public Property RedirectURL() As String
    Public Property Commission() As Decimal

    Public Property ApplicationRef As String
    Public Property ValidationErrors As List(Of String)
    Public Property Reason As String
End Class
```

Comment: why not deserialize it?

Comment: Have you heard of a company called 'Newtonsoft'?

Comment: Take a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserialize.aspx

Comment: deserialize ? please give me some more info

Comment: @user3703522 There are libraries for doing this. Trying to parse the string yourself if not the way to go. Search for "Newtonsoft" and/or look ad the link from duDE.

Comment: Even doing a [google search on your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=parsing+json+in+vb.net&oq=parsing+json+in+vb.net&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.384j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) shows promising results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28205195/1070452

Comment: perhaps you should share a link to the complete JSON.  `SandhurstData` does not match the bit posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is the way to go. It's super easy to do:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim json as String = "{'Id':'8151302', 'Status':'Accepted', 'Response':'0', 'Price':'0.88', 'Detail':'https://api.test.com/Redirect/Index 3eae1b02'}"
    Dim deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of SandhurstData)(json)

    Console.WriteLine(deserialized)
End Sub

Public Class SandhurstData
    Public Id as String
    Public Status as String
    Public Response as String
    Public Price as Double
    Public Detail as String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() as String
        return String.Format("Id: {1} {0}Status: {2} {0}Response: {3} {0}Price: {4} {0}Detail: {5}", Environment.NewLine, Id, Status, Response, Price, Detail)
    End Function
End Class
```

If the `DeserializeObject` method throws errors, it's likely because your JSON is invalid or does not match the target object.

Example fiddle: [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/upT86l)